# How can I make a div fade out when it is clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, fade

So basically I have a button and when the user clicks it, a div fades in. I would like it to fade out when the user clicks anywhere on the div. (the div takes up the entire screen)

Here is what I have so far, it basically just fades in the div when you click the "about" button. I need it to fade out whenever I click anywhere on the screen.

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#fadeContent').click(function(){
    $('#bodyContent').fadeIn(500);
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color:black;
}

#bodyContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;      left;0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background:#454545;
  z-index: 100;
}

#home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#projects {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 54%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 71%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#home:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#about:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#projects:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contact:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>  
<body>
    
    <button id="home">Home</button>
    <button id="fadeContent" class="about">About</button>
    <button id="projects">Projects</button>
    <button id="contact">Contact</button>
    
      <div id="bodyContent">    
            <h1>Page</h1>
            <p>Content</p>      
      </div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What control would a keyboard-only user tab to and "click" in order to hide the div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a click listener to the body content you just faded in, and then fade it out!

```js
$(function() {
  
  $('#fadeContent').click(function(){
    var bodyContent = $('#bodyContent')
    bodyContent.fadeIn(500);
    bodyContent.click(function() {
      $(this).fadeOut(500);
    })
  });
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  color: #ccc;
  z-index: -100;
  background-color:black;
}

#bodyContent{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;      left;0;
  width:100%; height:100%;
  background:#454545;
  z-index: 100;
}

#home {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

.about {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 37%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#projects {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 54%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    width: 16%;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid #FFF;
    margin-top: 12%;
    margin-left: 71%;
    height: 3em;
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-radius: 4px;
    animation: fadein 2s;
    -moz-animation: fadein 2s; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-animation: fadein 2s; /* Safari and Chrome */
}

#home:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#about:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#projects:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#contact:hover {
    color: #1dd2e2;
    border: 3px solid #18bdef;
    font-weight: bold;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadein { /* Safari and Chrome */
    from {
        opacity:0;
    }
    to {
        opacity:1;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Home</title>
    
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro|Play" rel="stylesheet">
    
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://rawgit.com/fralec/elegantShareJS/master/css/elegant.css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>  
<body>
    
    <button id="home">Home</button>
    <button id="fadeContent" class="about">About</button>
    <button id="projects">Projects</button>
    <button id="contact">Contact</button>
    
      <div id="bodyContent">    
            <h1>Page</h1>
            <p>Content</p>      
      </div>
    
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/elegant.js"></script>
    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/transition.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped. :)

Comment: No problem, please mark it as correct if it adequately answered your question!

Answer (score 0):

Just hookup the `fadeOut` into the click event when you are calling `fadeIn`.

```
$('#fadeContent').click(function(){
    $('#bodyContent').click(function() { 
       $(this).fadeOut(500); 
    }).fadeIn(500);
});
```

**EDIT**

The code above will keeping connecting the event handler every time you click the button. On the assumption that all your buttons will load and show content and clicking the content should always return to the buttons consider;

```
var $content = $('#bodyContent');
$('body').on('click','button', function() {
    $content.fadeIn(500);
});
$content.on('click', function() {
   $content.fadeOut(500);
});
```

You can then attach click events for the individual buttons to retrieve and assign the specific content into `#bodyContent` without also having to hook in the fadeIn/fadeOut.